# rosbridge unable to load the manifest for the package

Tags: manifest, ros

I am using rosbridge. My current ros_distro is `melodic`. I cannot subscribe to custom messages with an `error : Unable to load the manifest for package <pkg_name>`. I `sourced` the bash file in another terminal : `. ./devel/setup.bash` and used `rospack find <pkg_name>` but this also gives an error : package not found.

This is strange as I can publish and subscribe to the same topic in ROS.

My directory structure looks like following :

```
overlay_ws
  build
  devel
  src
    CMakeLists.txt
    ros_tutorials
      CMakeLists.txt
      package.xml
      msg
        msg1
        msg2
        msg3
      scripts
        talker.py
```

Here is the `package.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>ros_tutorials</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The demo package</description>

  <!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag -->
  <!-- Example:  -->
  <!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> -->
  <maintainer email="vishal@todo.todo">vishal</maintainer>


  <!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag -->
  <!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
  <!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 -->
  <license>TODO</license>


  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>



  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>
```

Comment: It is possible that you have a tainted workspace by means of package names or manifest file. Please give insights on your workspace structure an the corresponding manifest files.

Comment: You can also try verbose execution of rospack or catkin_find. It should give you some hints what goes wrong.

Comment: I have edited the question, is this what you meant ?

Comment: Ok, nice! Please add the content of your `package.xml`.

Comment: added the package.xml as well.

Comment: Are You using catkin_make or catkin build?